# dataframe select contiguous spans upon meeting condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume, I have the list of stopwords:

```
STOP = ['under', 'its', 'agreement', 'financed']
```

For the given dataframe:

```
lst = ['Kan.-based National', 'Kan.-based National Pizza', 'stock market', 
   'Pittsburg Kan.-based National Pizza', 'the stock market', 'revolving credit',
   'revolving credit agreement', 'its revolving credit agreement', 'under its revolving credit agreement', 
   'financed under its revolving credit agreement']

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

which is:

```
0   Kan.-based National
1   Kan.-based National Pizza
2   stock market
3   Pittsburg Kan.-based National Pizza
4   the stock market
5   revolving credit
6   revolving credit agreement
7   its revolving credit agreement
8   under its revolving credit agreement
9   financed under its revolving credit agreement
```

I want to obtain:

```
out = ['Pittsburg Kan.-based National Pizza', 'the stock market', 'revolving credit',
       'revolving credit agreement', 'its revolving credit agreement', 'under its revolving credit agreement', 
       'financed under its revolving credit agreement']

df_out = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

which is:

```
0   Pittsburg Kan.-based National Pizza
1   the stock market
2   revolving credit
3   revolving credit agreement
4   its revolving credit agreement
5   under its revolving credit agreement
6   financed under its revolving credit agreement
```

**Note:** The order of rows isn't important.

**Explanation:**

Since, `'Kan.-based National'` and `'Kan.-based National Pizza'` differ by just one word `'Pizza'` and there are no words present from the `STOP` list, we want to choose the longest span, i.e. `'Kan.-based National Pizza'`.
But, `'Pittsburg Kan.-based National Pizza'` also differs from `'Kan.-based National Pizza'` by just one word `'Pittsburg'` and there are no words present from the `STOP` list, we want to choose the longest span, i.e. `'Pittsburg Kan.-based National Pizza'`.

We CANNOT choose `'financed under its revolving credit agreement'` as the longest span starting with `'revolving credit'` because the words are present in the `STOP` list. Hence, we will NOT delete it's smaller spans.

Alternatively, on a side track, if the string starts with (a|an|the) and the difference between it's common spans is just one word. For eg - `"stock market"` and `"the stock market"`, we want to choose the longest span, i.e, `"the stock market"`.

I tried to do:

```
delete_from_best_constituents = []
for u in best_parse_constituents:
    for v in best_parse_constituents:
        if u.lower().startswith('the') or v.lower().startswith('the'):
            u_part = u.lower().split('the')[-1].strip()
            v_part =  v.lower().split('the')[-1].strip()
            cond1 = all([w.lower() not in STOP for w in u_part.split()])
            cond2 = all([w.lower() not in STOP for w in v_part.split()])
            if u_part == v.lower() or v_part == u.lower() and cond1 and cond2:
                if not u.lower().startswith('the'):
                    delete_from_best_constituents.append(u)
```

Comment: Suppose that ***XS*** is a set of strings. Let ***YS*** be the set of ***X*** in ***XS*** such that for all ***X-hat***  in ***XS***, ***X-hat*** is not a substring of ***X***. For example, if ***XS*** is `{"blue", "blue egg", "hello", "hello world"}` then `YS` is `{"blue egg", "hello world"}`? Are you trying to compute ***YS***? Are you trying to delete all of the short sub-strings? I can't tell what you are trying to do. Do you want to keep only the longer super-strings?

Comment: Is it the case that anytime you find a string which is sub-string of another, you delete the short string and keep the longer string? For example if you find both `"hello world"` and `"hello"` you keep `"hello world"` and discard `"hello"`?

Comment: You write that we cannot choose '"financed under its revolving credit agreement"' to be the longest string ***STARTING*** with '"revolving credit"' That does not even make sense. The string `"financed under its revolving credit agreement"` does ***NOT*** begin with the string "revolving credit"'.

Comment: You write, "We can't do [BLAH] because ***the words*** are present in the `STOP` list." What exactly are "***the words***?" Exactly which words from the `STOP` list cause the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a definition of what a "***span***" is? You keep talking about "the ***span*** of this", "the ***span*** that", et cetera, but you never said what a "***span***" is exactly. Can you please include a hyperlink to definition of "***span***" in your question?

Comment: It seems like you have partially parsed, or interpreted, a string. You want our help parsing it the rest-of-the-way. Can you please edit your question to include a copy of the raw input? What did the string look like before you did any parsing at all? Is the following the original string you started with? `"Pittsburg Kan.-based National Pizza is financed under its revolving credit agreement"` Where did `"stock market"` come from? You gave us an intermediate result. A temporary, partially-parsed mess. I want to see the original English text before you attempted to parse it.